# Change font color of variable in Java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML, CSS, and Java programming.
I'm trying to change the color and text of an HTML element in JavaScript. Here is what I have. (`Pressure_OK` is tied to an input; you can manually set it to 0 or 1.) Basically, if the input is 0, then I want it to pass `Okay` in text form, but I want the text to be green.  Otherwise, I want it to be `Not Okay` in red.

```
<p  id="pressure"></p>

<script>
var Pressure;
if ('"Pressure_Ok"'==1)
{
    Pressure ="Okay"; 
    press = document.getElementById("pressure").innerHTML = Pressure;
    press.style.color= 'green';
}
else
{
    Pressure ="Gas Pressure: Not Okay"; 
    press = document.getElementById("pressure").innerHTML = Pressure;
    press.style.color= 'red';
}
</script>
```

Comment: There are basic syntax errors. read some tutorials on Javascript.

Comment: Where is your input field ? and what is `'"Pressure_Ok"'` is this your variable name which holds the value ?

Comment: The issue is `press` is not assigned the DOM object, but it's `.innerHTML`.  You need to `var press = document.getElementById("pressure");` and THEN on another line, assign the `textContent` (if you're not assigning HTML, don't use `innerHTML`. Then set the DOM color

Comment: Remember it's **JavaScript** not **Java**.

Comment: Pressure_OK is a vale i get from a server. You can replace it with a var value and give it a value of 0 or 1. When i get a value of 1 from the server it indicates that the pressure sensor is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the element or font color to green instead of the innerHtml? I'm fairly certain you're trying to use a CSS style on a string, which shouldn't do anything.

If you want to set the font color to green then you should be changing the font color, not the style color.

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var result = str.fontcolor("green");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fontcolor.asp

One thing to watch out for with JS and JQ is exactly what object you're operating on. Where you have

```
press = document.getElementById("pressure").innerHTML
```

is where the problem is, since on the next line you're acting on the innerHtml of the element and not the element itself.

Aka, try this:

```
press = document.getElementById("pressure")
press.innerHTML = Pressure;
press.innerHTML.fontcolor("red");
```

or conversely:

```
press = document.getElementById("pressure")
press.innerHTML = Pressure;
press.style.color = "red";
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. To make it more clear what im doing is, i have a value which is Pressure_OK. That value will either be a 0 or 1. (this is done using a pressure sensor which is connected to a server. so basically this sensor can go off or on. With that in mind im trying to use a web page to give the status. So if its on,, i want to display okay on the web page. other wise not okay. I just want to incorporate some color to the string. green as good, red as bad.

Comment: I'd use the second option to just change the style color (less mess and stuff to keep track of imho). If you want easier syntax I'd even go as far as to suggest adding/using Jquery (check out the answer below this one), although since you're new to web tech it's best to start with vanilla JS to get a feel for the DOM and such.

Another tip, JS is loosely typed. If you're '"Pressure_OK"' var is an int then you don't need the ==1 at all, you can just check if('"Pressure_OK"'){ //stuff }

JS will assume *almost* anything other than an empty/null string or 0 is true.

Comment: Also I'm a noob to SO! If I helped to answer your Q then remember to mark my A! I need more pts so I can post stuff.

Comment: absolutely, i will give it a try. at the moment im only seeing not oky even though the sensor is on. i will need to dig a bit deeper on why that is the case. thanks!!

Comment: Np. I'd suggest verifying that  '"Pressure_OK"' will return how you want it to in the dev console of your browser, since that's you're only check that could fail.

Comment: Hey Erik, i finally got it to receive the data from the server. my syntax was incorrect.  Thanks!. I had another question though. I would need to refresh the website in order for it to pick up the new value. is their a way to have it keep checking and pick up the new value (if it turns off) without refreshing the page?

Comment: Absolutely there's a way! Search for 'ajax long polling' or 'ajax heart beat', it's a technique that utilizes setTimeout from JS to continuously make requests over an interval. I'd ask about this in a separate question, though.

Comment: Thank Erik, I will mess around with it and post a new question if I run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the syntax but I dont know what are you trying to achieve

```js
var Pressure;
if ('"Pressure_Ok"'==1)
{
      Pressure ="Okay"; 
      var press = document.getElementById("pressure")
      press.innerHTML = Pressure;
      press.style.color= 'green';
}
else
{
      Pressure ="Gas Pressure: Not Okay"; 
      var press = document.getElementById("pressure")
      press.innerHTML = Pressure;
      press.style.color= 'red';
}
```

```html
<span id="pressure"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p  id="pressure"></p>

<script>
var Pressure;
if ('"Pressure_Ok"'==1){
Pressure ="Okay"; 
press = document.getElementById("pressure").innerHTML = Pressure;
document.getElementById("pressure").style.color= 'green';

}
else{
Pressure ="Gas Pressure: Not Okay"; 
press = document.getElementById("pressure").innerHTML = Pressure;
document.getElementById("pressure").style.color= 'red';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks user! i'llk give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery for simplification

```
  $("#pressure").css("color","red");
```

Comment: I'll take a look at Jquery. I'm not sure what it is to be honest, soi will try to read about it first.

Comment: @trace Learn standard JS before using jQuery. Although you might find jQuery easier to start with, it can hide JS fundamentals from you.

Comment: Will do. I know its alot to digest but it will take time. In the meantime, thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you dont want to use jQuery you can easily use the javascript 

              `document.getElementById("pressure").style.color="red";`